# Running Windows 10 on laptop dedicated GPU

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have an older laptop with Intel HD Graphics 4000 and nVidia GeForce GT650M. I bought a monitor that supports Quad HD, but the Intel HD Graphics 4000 does not support it. So I would like to disable it completely and use only the dedicated GPU.

Is this possible? I am aware of the ability to switch the GPU for rendering during playing games etc. But I have not been able to find a mention of forcing its usage to allow the use of higher resolutions on a monitor.

In the NVIDIA Control Panel, I found a diagram that seems to indicate, that the dedicated GPU has no physical outputs. [image: diagram]
Does this mean there is no way to use the GPU to get to QuadHD?

Comment: "Is this possible?" - No

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, with the way my laptop is constructed, this is not possible. As found in [notebookcheck](https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-650M.71887.0.html) description of the GPU:

> However, as most laptops will feature Optimus, the integrated GPU will likely have direct control over the display ports and may limit the feature set available by the Nvidia Kepler cards.

The GPU would indeed need to have a physical output.